# How to bulk delete all WordPress subscribers?

Tags: mysql, spam

I have 20,000 fake subscribers I'd like to get rid of. The admin panel only lets you delete 200 at a time.

How can I bulk delete all Wordpress subscribers via MySQL?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up deleting all users who had not made a post using the following two queries:

First:

```
DELETE FROM wp_users
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts)
```

Second:

```
DELETE
FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM wp_users)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'role=subscriber' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    wp_delete_user( $user_id );
}
```

Comment: in `functions.php`?

Comment: If you run query  for once then you can use in functions.php with 
if( isset($_GET['remove_user'])){
// Here add code
}
Now call site url like : site-url.com/?remove_uesr

Comment: like this way: `siteurl.com?remove_user` ?

Comment: Once you delete subscriber you can delete script.

Comment: siteurl.com/?remove_user

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was asked a long while ago, but, if you happen across this like I did, this could help. Running this SQL in phpMyAdmin will remove all **subscribers** in a WordPress database.

```
DELETE wp_users, wp_usermeta
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
```

Replace `wp_` with whatever your table prefix is. I ran something similar to remove customers and it worked in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just joined Stack Exchange, so I'm not allowed to upvote someone's comment yet, but SYPOMark's SQL worked like a charm for me. I had thousands of likely spam subscribers. It's always good to make a quick backup of relevant database tables first, just in case something goes very wrong.